# How to track a crash in iOS extension-custom keyboard in UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, uianimation, custom-keyboard

How do I know if my custom keyboard crashed when using UIAutomation to do auto-testing?
Now I'm checking if the keyboard is changed to system keyboard. If so, the custom keyboard is considered as crashed.

Comment: integrate crashlytics in your project Please go through the link:
https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/ios

Comment: Thanks Abbie, but I want to use UI Automation to custom my test.